# What is a basis for $\mathrm{Hom}_K(K^n,K^m)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be a field.  Then $\mathrm{Hom}_K(K^n,K^m)$ is a vector space over $K$. What is a basis for $\mathrm{Hom}_K(K^n,K^m)$? What is the dimension?

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Linear transformations can be represented with matrices.

Comment: You must keep your keyboard pretty well-greased...

Comment: Haha, yeah :) It's a combination of hints being quicker to write, and my being fueled by extreme avoidance to my work...

Comment: Yes, its dimension is $mn$. Basis are the matrices $A_{i,j}$, which has 1 in the $(i,j)^{th}$ place and zero everywhere.

Comment: @efj: That's the right dimension, but you've found a basis for the set $\mathrm{M}_{m\times n}(K)$ of $m\times n$ matrices, not the set $\mathrm{Hom}_K(K^n,K^m)$ of linear transformations from $K^n$ to $K^m$. Now you need to "convert" those matrices back into linear transformations.

Comment: Yes, Its oK. I will find it

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Any such homomorphism is determined by its value on the basis elements.